# jquery image/description replacement with fade

Tags: jquery

I am simply(for you, not me) trying to add image fading to the following code kindly provided by www.webdesignerwall.com.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("h2").append('<em></em>')
     $(".thumbs a").click(function(){
       var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
       var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");
       $("#largeImg").attr({ src: largePath, alt: largeAlt });  
       $("h2 em").html(" (" + largeAlt + ")"); return false;
     });
});
```

I have so far lost a lot of sleep/hair attempting to tie in a fading function from other code. 
And from that other code, I have been unable to find anything that also has the .append function like this one has.
I know this is childs play for most of you Jquery/javascript professionals. Unfortunately, the webdev gods were not as kind to me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("h2").append('<em></em>')
     $(".thumbs a").click(function(){
       var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
       var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");
       $("h2 em").hide();
       $("#largeImg").load(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn();
            $("h2 em").html(" (" + largeAlt + ")").fadeIn();
       }).attr({ src: largePath, alt: largeAlt }).hide();  
        return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: it will fadein AFTER the image is loaded... if you can ignore that and want it DIRECTLY to fade in, write a comment...

Comment: oc california? :D i only know, that this is a tv-series :D
;) i'm from germany, but i'll tell you, if i *EVER* will be there ;) thanx!